# Magento 2 Transactional Email Variables

Tags: magento2

Transactional email variables not passing to template. I'm defining the email variables and sending the email as such.

```
class Sendemail
{

   /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    private $_transportBuilder;

  public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder){

    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
  }

  public function sendEmail($sender, $recipient, $template, $store)
  {



    $retrievalcode = "somecustomcode";    
    $vars = Array('retrieval_code' => $retrievalcode);

     $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $store])
            ->setTemplateVars($vars)
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($recipient)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
  }

}
```

The email is sending but it not including the defined template variable. Any suggestions would be appreciated.The variable is being call in the transactional email template as:

```
{{var retrieval_code}}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Sendemail
{
    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    private $_transportBuilder;

    public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder){

        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    }

    public function sendEmail($sender, $recipient, $template, $storeId)
    {
        $parseDataVars = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();

        $retrievalcode = "somecustomcode";
        $parseDataVars->setData(array('retrieval_code' => $retrievalcode));

        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars(array('data' => $parseDataVars))
            ->setFrom($sender)
            ->addTo($recipient)
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: then reference var in template with `{{var data.retrieval_code}}`